# Check cell's location in matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have a 7x7 matrix (declared as `uint8_t*`):

```
x B B B B B x
B S S S S S B
B S S S S S B
B S S S S S B
B S S S S S B
B S S S S S B
x B B B B B x
```

Where `x` are the edges, `B` is the border, and `S` is the rest of the matrix.

I need to know where a given cell *i* is -- in the borders, edges, or inside the matrix, and do an operation on it if it's inside the matrix on not on any borders or edges. Also, would it just be better to use a multidimensional-array (`uint8_t**`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for which representation is better, that depends on the rest of your code. Either way will work.

As for how to tell the edges from the middle, if `i%7 == 0` you're on the left edge, if `i%7 == 6` you're on the right edge. If `i < 7` you're at the top, and if `i >= 56` you're at the bottom edge. If none of those, then you're in the middle.

And that gets to which representation is better: those mod operations are slow, so if you're going to be doing a lot of that, then the 2-d array is better. But if you're mostly just indexing through serially, 1-d should be faster. There are other considerations too, of course -- that's just something to think about.